# How To Change CineMachine Dead Zone Width With Code? UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

So I was wondering how I could change my dead zone width or height with coding I have a collision detector so when my player collides with that rectangle I want to change the dead zone width to ***2*** but I have no idea on how to do this I tried to search online for an answer but couldn't so I wanted to ask here to see if anyone knows the answer.

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("dead"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Dead Zone Width Changed");
    }
}
```

**Rest of My Code:**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class stopcamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CinemachineVirtualCamera cam;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("dead"))
        {
            var composer = cam.GetCinemachineComponent<CinemachineComposer>();
            composer.m_DeadZoneWidth = 2f;
            Debug.Log("saman the third");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to change the dead zone width to 2

To change a specific value of your Cinemachine virtual camera. You first need to get the [`ComponentBase`](https://documentation.help/Cinemachine/73036ab7-f9fd-7a16-67c8-82a9a70496b8.htm) of either (`Aim`, `Body`, or `Noise`), depending on which stage you want to change the values at. You can do that with [`GetCinemachineComponent(CinemachineCore.Stage.Body)`](https://documentation.help/Cinemachine/ace43872-327c-8582-4bce-c3c5c76805e0.htm).

To then change the value you need to ensure the type your [`ComponentBase`](https://documentation.help/Cinemachine/73036ab7-f9fd-7a16-67c8-82a9a70496b8.htm) is set to the same value as in the Inspector. In your case that would be the [`CineMachineFramingTransposer`](https://documentation.help/Cinemachine/c1e40dce-d7c3-19cf-a963-4d6a819ddb34.htm).

**Example:**

```cs
[SerializeField]
private CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCam;

private CinemachineComponentBase componentBase;

private void Start() {
    // Get the componentBase of our virutalCam to adjust its values via code.
    componentBase = virtualCam.GetCinemachineComponent(CinemachineCore.Stage.Body);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag("dead")) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the CinemachineCore.Stage.Body ComponentBase,
    // is set to the CinemachineFramingTransposer.
    if (componentBase is CinemachineFramingTransposer) {
        var framingTransposer = componentBase as CinemachineFramingTransposer;
        // Now we can change all its values easily.
        framingTransposer.m_DeadZoneWidth = 2f;
        Debug.Log("Dead Zone Width Changed");
    }
}
```